# React app is not loading from docker image in local

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

> My Docker file

```
# FROM node:16.14.2
FROM node:alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

Command to run image: docker run -it -d -p 4001:4001 react-app:test2

> Project structure

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmsPw.png)

> Output after docker run
> [result after docker run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmsPw.png)

Comment: maybe share the code that launches your app. My assumption would be it's something to do with the container ip/localhost/0.0.0.0 etc.

Comment: u sure ur dockerfile is complete? lookslike the applicatiion is missing from the /workdir

Comment: Right before ```CMD```, try ```COPY .  ./```

Comment: I tried `COPY .  /app/` and `COPY .  .` . Still it's the same issue.
I suspect application is not copied to working directory but I'm not sure what to do for that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please find the git hub link which I created just to practice the docker
[github](https://github.com/manoharr180/reactpracticeapp)

Answer (score 1):

Based on this context, a possible mistake for me is basically that you do not copy the rest of the source code correctly.

Try to be more consistent in the Dockerfile, also have a look at the multistage Docker build (within the same file) to optimise the image.
Anyway, your file should be something like:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

Comment: [github link](https://github.com/manoharr180/reactpracticeapp) if you need proj reference

Comment: I added another answer, thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in the repo, I managed to spot the following problem.It's neither the Dockerfile, nor the code itslef. It throws some warnings though.

Implicitly, the application is supposed to be running on port 3000, if it is not chnaged manually at some point (in this project there are only default settings). Thus the application starts correclty on **port 3000**, However you expose **4001:4001**. On this port **nothing is running** according to this Dockerfile.

Try using port 3000 instead and it should work just fine:

```
 docker run -it -d -p 3000:3000 <image-name>:<image-tag>
```

Comment: Yep, it worked on **port 3000** . Any suggestion or input to run on different port numbers from docker image?

Comment: Either map the docker ports like 4001:3000, or change the port of the React application itself